# macOS Sierra/High Sierra and IPv6 DNS via SLACC

Tags: network, macos, dns, ipv6

In my (dual stack) network, a router provides IPv6 addresses and DNS servers (RDNSS) via router advertising. There is no DHCPv6 server running and I want my mac to accept the DNS servers being provided via RA (RDNSS). Address acceptance out of advertising is well running. Wireshark also shows that the RDNSS addresses are sent properly and the flags are set as configured on the router. IPv4 is configured via DHCP...

I have now played through all combinations of the M, O, A Flags, found this very enlightening article [about SLACC on different systems](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-v6ops-dhcpv6-slaac-problem-07) but still can't get managed that my Macs show the DNS IPv6 Servers in the known DNS Servers area of the system control.

Im a still not sure whether I have to look further on the router side or on the client side. While all other systems in this network (Linux, Windows) are working properly, I suspect now the client side (i.e. Macs).

Is there any *sysctl* parameter I might miss out/consider or any daemon which must run (e.g. a similar thing like rdnssd on Linux)?